# Alphabetical range not displaying in IntelliJ IDEA console as expected

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, range

I'm following a tutorial on `Range` [here](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-2-learning-basics-scala-programming/scala-tutorial-learn-use-range-inclusive-exclusive/). The sample code is

```
val alphabetRangeFromAToZ = 'a' to 'z'
println(s"Range of alphabets from a to z = $alphabetRangeFromAToZ")
```

The expected output according to the tutorial is:

```
Range of alphabets from a to z = NumericRange(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)
```

What I actually get in the IntelliJ IDEA console output is:

```
Range of alphabets from a to z = NumericRange a to z
```

Is this expected behavior for IDEA? Can I configure IDEA in some manner to display the output in the way the tutorial shows the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to you using a newer Scala version than the tutorial author.  The behavior was changed in Scala 2.12.  The output in the tutorial is how it used to work and the output you are seeing is the new behavior.

If you want to get a String showing all of the included elements you can use th `mkString` method on range

```
val range = 'a' to 'z'
println(range.mkString(", "))
```

prints

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
```

Comment: Is it possible to revert to the old behavior or at least get some more information from the output?

Comment: @user38352 Added details on how to print the full contents to my answer